# how to retrieve values of various checkbox groups from one jsp page to another

Tags: jsp

Here's the sample code

```
<input type="radio" name="r1" value="A">
<input type="radio" name="r1" value="B">


<input type="radio" name="r2" value="X">
<input type="radio" name="r2" value="Y">
```

and so on

```
<input type="radio" name="r_" value="P">
<input type="radio" name="r_" value="Q">
```

Here I'd retrieved this radio button boxes from the database and shown on a jsp page through a while loop

```
While(resultSet.next()){
```

}

Now i've to check the values selected by the user on another jsp page.
So, how could i retrieve the checked values?
The main problem is that, in the database the number of rows may be incremented or decremented by the administrator. so i don't need to change the code every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the total amount of `r_` to a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="count" value="${count}" />
```

Get it as follows:

```
int count = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("count"));
```

And get all checkbox values as follows:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
    String[] checked = request.getParameterValues("r" + i);
    // ...
}
```